# Angular2+Webpack how should I output html file with templateUrl?

Tags: angular, webpack

I write a component that it uses templateUrl to include a html file

```
/*component*/
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
/*html*/
<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
```

webpack config like

```
  {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loaders: [
      'awesome-typescript-loader'
    ],
    exclude: [/node_modules/,/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
  },{
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: 'raw-loader',
    exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, "index.html")]
  }

new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: 'index.html' })
```

output js file should including the html, but it doesn't have

it's my code in github
https://github.com/jiaming0708/ng2-webpack

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a angular2-template-loader so you don't need to write require it will do the that job for you and you can keep writing simple syntax like

```
 templateUrl: './app.component.html'
```

instead of

```
template: require('./my-component.html')
```

### How does it work

The angular2-template-loader searches for templateUrl and styleUrls declarations inside of the Angular 2 Component metadata and replaces the paths with the corresponding require statement.

### How to add it in my project

```
npm install angular2-template-loader --save-dev
```

Small change in webpack.config

```
loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
```

Use html-loader instead of raw loader

```
 {test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html'}
```

[Learn more](https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular2-template-loader)

Comment: I followed your step, but I got an error, ypeError: this.ts.getAutomaticTypeDirectiveNames is not a function.
I have no idea what do I lose....orz

Comment: I downed grade the version to older, angular2-template-loader(0.4.0), awesome-typescript-loader(1.1.1), that was working.

Comment: Good I thing there is a issue with versions. I use ts-loader latest and angular2-template-loader latest and it works fine. Please accept the answer if it helped 

Comment: Be Carefull, what quotation marks you are using the ES6 \`./template.html` are NOT working use normal quotation marks.

Comment: Why use the html loader over the raw loader?

Answer (score 5):

I discovered [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) that it did not using require and using templateUrl.

config

```
  {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loaders: [
      'awesome-typescript-loader',
      'angular2-template-loader',
      '@angularclass/hmr-loader'
    ],
    exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
  },
  {
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: 'raw-loader',
    exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
  }
```

component

```
  templateUrl: './home.template.html'
```

Why they can do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the html in the JS bundle, use the `raw` loader, just as you did. However, webpack does not recognize the file for you, if you don't `require` it. Instead of using `templateUrl`, use `template`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: require('./my-component.html')
})
```

If you want a separate html file in the output, use the [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader) and `templateUrl`

Comment: Wonderful, It works!!
But I got an error, that is [error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.]
What should I do to resolve this error??

Comment: Simply, include types for requirejs.